# Big unwanted space in subview navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There is a huge space in my subview navigation bar.

I was assuming by adding `trailing` buttons, it would align everything nicely to the right of the `back` button.

This is my main view:

[image]

Now this is my subview:

[image]

Look at the huge gap at the top. I want the `plus` button to be to the right of the `back` button. Do I need to just create a custom back button for this or what?

Here is my code for the subview:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Text("hello world")
            Text("hello world")
            Text("hello world")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(todoList.title!)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.add = true
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                })
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I also want to remove the text from the `back` button so it's just an image.

To summarize:

- I want the `plus` button at the top to the right of the `back` button
- I want to remove the `back` button text, which reads `ColorTodo` in this example

Is there a SwiftUI native way of doing this or do I need a custom back button and to disable the default one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason for the extra space is that you are wrapping a `NavigationView` inside a `NavigationView`; remove the one inside your subview, and the plus button will be at the right height.

As for removing the text, yes, you would need to hide the default back button and replace it with your own. Subview might look something like

```
struct SubView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
            List {
                Text("hello world")
                Text("hello world")
                Text("hello world")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(todoList.title!, displayMode: .inline) // 1
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton, trailing: addButton)
    }

    var backButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                Text("Back") // 2
            }
        })
    }

    var addButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.add = true
        }, label: {
            ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                Rectangle() // 3
                    .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.0001)) // 4
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Although `displayMode: .inline` is not necessary, the default large title style looks a bit strange animating in and out.
2. You can remove this if you want (but see below)
3. This rectangle is here to increase tap target size, as the default button will only be the size of the plus icon, which is probably too small.
4. The rectangle can't be completely transparent, or it will not register taps.

Comment: This worked. I also want to point out that sub views will automatically contain a navigation view from the parent view when navigationlinks are used. I wasn’t aware of this.